# How can I have my SQL Server access to AD group?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a group in AD that logins to windows and what I want to do is to grant the same AD group access to SQL Server using the AD credentials.

My SQL Server is setup to use mixed mode (windows and SQL Server logins).

So lets say my AD group name is : `MyCompanyGroup`

I want to grant access to that group to be able to connect to SQL Server.

Can anybody guide me how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: I think just `CREATE LOGIN [YourDomain\YourGroup] FROM WINDOWS WITH DEFAULT_DATABASE=[foo]`. If not you can do this through the GUI. Click "Search" then "Advanced". By default groups don't show up so click "Object Types" and select "Groups" then click "Find Now" to see a list of all Groups.

Comment: well i have 100+ instance of sql server, how would you do in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 100+ SQL Server instances, you have to run this script 100+ times.

Also: you will need to create specific **users** for that login in those databases that the login should have access to.

Basically use something like:

```
USE (database name)
CREATE USER (username) FOR LOGIN (loginname)
```

See the MSDN [How-To: Create a Database User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa337545.aspx) for detailed info.

But everything can be scripted. And with a decent tool like [Red-Gate SQL MultiScript](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dba/sql-multi-script/), you can even have it executed on all your 100+ instances automagically.